# How do I find the names of classes in modules for TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, fs

So in this code:

```
import * as fs from "fs"

class FsAsyncFactory {

    private static fsSync: any

}

export default FsAsyncFactory
```

I've put the type of this prop `private static fsSync: any` as `any` but it's going to be the fs variable imported at the top - how do I figure out what the class is called?

I guessed something like `FileSystem` but it didn't work. I don't have a deep enough understanding of TypeScript to figure it out.

I have `"@types/node": "^8.0.50",` in my dev dependencies and I've gone into `node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts` but I can't see anything that quite makes sense? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the "type of" command of typescript.

```
import * as fs from "fs"

class FsAsyncFactory {

   private static fsSync: typeof fs

}

export default FsAsyncFactory
```

And then inside your class

```
constructor(){
 //...//
 FsAsyncFactory.fsSync. //ide recognizes fsSync is of type "fs" and gives you full prediction of fs functions
 //...//
}
```

**Question: What is this typeof and why cant I use just class names?**

Basically as I understand by reading the `node/index.d.ts` the `fs` is just a module that is being exported. Basically an object with some typed functions with their own documentation. In that case we don't have a class name or an interface to declare our other variables which are equal to `fs`. The `typeof` command of typescript is a **type query**, basically if no class or interface is implemented on the source variable it will just expect the same properties of the source to be presented in the target.

Another approach with your issue could be the use of **Type Aliases**

```
import * as fs from "fs"
type FileSystem = typeof fs

class FsAsyncFactory {

   private static fsSync: FileSystem

}

export default FsAsyncFactory
```

This will create a new type called `FileSystem` which will expect every object which is declared as `FileSystem` type, to implement every function of the `fs` module.

**Question: How can I use Bluebird's promisifyAll with typescript?**

```
import * as fs from "fs"
import * as Bluebird from "bluebird"

const fsProm : FileSystem = Bluebird.promisifyAll(fs)

fsProm.writeFile('filename','some data') // Typescript error function expects at least 3 parameters
   .then(console.log)
```

Unfortunately, from my point of view promisifyAll will change a strict typed function to something else without leaving any definitions of what changed, that is very bad for typescript. After some search I couldn't find any solid solution that will work on all cases, check this [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8685).
Maybe your best bet is to declare your promisidied variable to type `any` and continue working without intellisense.

Comment: This works thanks! One more thing - can you explain why I have to use typeof instead of using a class name like I would with my own class definitions? Just so I know for future reference. Thanks!

Comment: Also I'm actually using bluebird to `promisifyAll` so TypeScript fails compilation on the calling code as `readFileAsync` isn't part of the definition of `fs` - any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: @ForceHero check the updated answer, I couldn't find all the answers in your questions but maybe I will point you to some direction.

Comment: Thanks so much! Very helpful